# How to call an activity inside View page indicator?

Tags: android

I have to load three layouts inside view page indicator.The three activity's are dynamic.They load contents from web services and also has grid view which gets its contents dynamically loaded.Is there any method to load activity inside view page indicator.I have used [JakeWhartons](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) view page indicator.

Comment: what do you mean by loading new activity inside new page indicator?? Do you mean you want to load new activity on page scroll(Change)

Comment: Ya while scrolling as in google playstore.Can I call a new activity inside it.

Comment: sreejith i think its using fragments . so in fragment we can load activities

Comment: Sir,I called startactivity inside but it is getting force closed

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951730/viewpager-and-fragments-whats-the-right-way-to-store-fragments-state)

Comment: provide more information show me what you have done till . post the code or log cat

Comment: if you need help you should provide more information .without knowing  what you have done how can i help?This was my [code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433281/android-fragment-pager-and-custom-page-indicator-viewpagerindicator-created-by)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since You are using view Pager you should make use of Fragments to get your need

Hope [this](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-example/) would hep you

**Edit:**

Th Logic i follow is `MainActivity extends FragmentActivity`

then in the main activity i will set custom `FragmentPagerAdapter` for `ViewPager`

eg: `ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter`

Then as you say for each category ( FEATURED,CATEGORIES ,TOP PAID ,TOP FREE )

I will create fragments .

But i think you need to use one Fragment for all categories .AFAIK i can't answer your need now .but i will figure to sort out

But  i want to ask something why don't you try to **switch case** on the string that you selected

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have used  JakeWharton library.And worked fine for me at times loading static pages.But loading dynamic pages it is not working.

Comment: I have to load activity like this                           @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View v=null;

     
   if(mContent.equalsIgnoreCase("Top News"))
    {  

    
    Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),activity_home.class);
    startActivity(i);
     }

Comment: mContent contains String as FEATURED,CATEGORIES ,TOP PAID ,TOP FREE in google play.I the contarol comes inside the if condition.What I want to know is how to start an activity inside this condition.

Comment: If this is your purpose . I don't know the answer